# how to delete NaN values in pandas while adding other columns' value to the very next row which has not NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe view:

```
index   date    B   N   S   y_B   y_N   y_S  f_price    y_price  p_change   price_day_t-2
1   2021-01-12  1   29  0   2.0   57.0  0.0  10250.0    10760.0  -1.0        11060.0
2   2021-01-13  0   67  0   1.0   29.0  0.0  9810.0     10250.0  -1.0        10760.0
3   2021-01-14  2   19  0   0.0   67.0  0.0  NaN         NaN     NaN           NaN
4   2021-01-15  1   6   0   2.0   19.0  0.0  NaN         NaN     NaN           NaN
5   2021-01-16  2   46  0   1.0   6.0   0.0  9340.0     9810.0   -1.0        10250.0
6   2021-01-17  3   22  0   2.0   46.0  0.0  NaN         NaN     NaN           NaN
7   2021-01-18  1   34  0   3.0   22.0  0.0  8890.0     9340.0   -1.0        9810.0
```

I want to delete rows with null values but at the same time, I want to add the other columns' values to the very next row without null values. which the result would be like this:

```
index   date    B   N   S   y_B   y_N   y_S  f_price    y_price  p_change   price_day_t-2
1   2021-01-12  1   29  0   2.0   57.0  0.0  10250.0    10760.0  -1.0        11060.0
2   2021-01-13  0   67  0   1.0   29.0  0.0  9810.0     10250.0  -1.0        10760.0
5   2021-01-16  5   71  0   3.0   92.0  0.0  9340.0     9810.0   -1.0        10250.0
7   2021-01-18  4   56  0   5.0   68.0  0.0  8890.0     9340.0   -1.0        9810.0
```

for example in row n.5 column "B", the result is 5 because of the aggregation 2+1+2. (the two other values [1] and [2] are from deleted rows)

How can I do this?

Comment: In last column are always missing values like in sample data?

Comment: yes... this sample table is the result of merging two other tables. and, null values are like in sample data and same as other columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups by comapre last column from back for non missing values with cumulative sum, then aggregate `sum` for all columns without `date`, it aggregate by `last` values per groups:

```
g = df.iloc[::-1, -1].notna().cumsum()

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'sum')
d['date'] = 'last'

df = df.groupby(g, sort=False).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         date  B   N  S  y_B   y_N  y_S  f_price  y_price  p_change  \
0  2021-01-12  1  29  0  2.0  57.0  0.0  10250.0  10760.0      -1.0   
1  2021-01-13  0  67  0  1.0  29.0  0.0   9810.0  10250.0      -1.0   
2  2021-01-16  5  71  0  3.0  92.0  0.0   9340.0   9810.0      -1.0   
3  2021-01-18  4  56  0  5.0  68.0  0.0   8890.0   9340.0      -1.0   

   price_day_t-2  
0        11060.0  
1        10760.0  
2        10250.0  
3         9810.0
```